# Find min in the same line of several files using sed/awk/grep?

Tags: bash, filter, grep, min

I have 3 files (they will getting more after a testing phase), each containing 66 lines with:

```
FIRST=156627343 LAST=156627575
FIRST=169555944 LAST=169556026
FIRST=236401800 LAST=236402020
FIRST=56685918  LAST=56686028
FIRST=123843179 LAST=123843334
FIRST=57879358  LAST=57879500
FIRST=57879358  LAST=57879500
FIRST=92956620  LAST=92956795
```

Most of the time, First&Last will be the same in each line for all files. However in some cases, there will be difference, like in line 1 of the second file:

```
FIRST=156627352 LAST=156627575
FIRST=169555944 LAST=169556026
FIRST=236401800 LAST=236402020
FIRST=56685918  LAST=56686028
FIRST=123843179 LAST=123843356
FIRST=57879358  LAST=57879500
FIRST=57879358  LAST=57879500
FIRST=92956620  LAST=92956795
```

I want to create a new file that contain max FIRST and min LAST. My approach is:

```
paste -d" " $file1 $file2 $file3  | while read from to; do echo "${from}" "${to}"; done > output.txt
```

But how can I filter this output?

Comment: So how is the expected output? Also, `comm -3 --nocheck-order f1 f2` kind of makes it.

Comment: Are you only concerened with the first line? Or all lines?

Comment: All 66 lines, comparing always the first line of file1 with the first line of file2 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
 awk '{ print (  $1 > $3 ? ( $1 > $5 ? $1 : $5 ) : ( $3 > $5 ? $3 : $5 )), (  $2 < $4 ? ( $2 < $6 ? $2 : $6 ) : ( $4 < $6 ? $4 : $6 )) }' output.txt
```

will give output as

```
FIRST=156627352 LAST=156627575
FIRST=169555944 LAST=169556026
FIRST=236401800 LAST=236402020
FIRST=56685918 LAST=56686028
FIRST=123843179 LAST=123843334
FIRST=57879358 LAST=57879500
FIRST=57879358 LAST=57879500
FIRST=92956620 LAST=92956795
```

Hope this is what you want

Comment: I don't think so. He is apparently looking for lines that do not match in both files.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: Thank you very much - that is exactly what I want. That is a good template for me - I will work on that so that I can do this with multiple files.

Comment: @federoqui: Sorry for being so unprecise

Comment: @user3401516 you are welcome. glad to know it worked

Answer (score 3):

To loop over all files and find the min/max:

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]=]+' '
    NR==FNR || $2 < first[FNR] {first[FNR] = $2} 
    NR==FNR || $4 > last[FNR]  {last[FNR]  = $4} 
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) 
            printf "FIRST=%s\tLAST=%s\n", first[i], last[i]
    }
' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: +1 Very elegant and too darned fast by 2 minutes! And, works for any number of input files all in one go.

Comment: I wonder why this is not working for me. The output is like "FIRST= LAST=" for every line.

Comment: I wonder too, but I need more details to do anything but wonder.

Answer (score 1):

This is a (rather more prosaic) pure Bash version of Glenn Jackman's excellent 'awk' solution:

```
declare -i -a min_first=()
declare -i -a max_last=()
declare -i line_idx
declare -i is_first_file=1
for file in "$@" ; do
    line_idx=0
    while IFS=$' \t\n=' read f1 first f3 last || [[ $f1 ]] ; do
        (( is_first_file || first < min_first[line_idx] )) \
            && min_first[line_idx]=first
        (( is_first_file || last > max_last[line_idx] )) \
            && max_last[line_idx]=last
        line_idx+=1
    done <"$file"

    is_first_file=0
done

for (( line_idx=0 ; line_idx < ${#min_first[@]} ; line_idx++ )) ; do
    echo "FIRST=${min_first[line_idx]} LAST=${max_last[line_idx]}"
done
```

It assumes that the list of files to process has been provded as command line arguments ("$@").

The '[[ $f1 ]]' is to ensure that the last line is processed in files where it is not terminated.

I haven't benchmarked it, but it will certainly be much slower than the 'awk' solution.  However, I'd expect it to be fast enough for up to 100 input files of the size described in the question.